# Difference between count distinct and distinct count KDB

Tags: kdb

What is the difference between "count distinct table" and "distinct count table" in KDB? I thought count distinct table gave me the number of distinct rows but distinct count table gives me a different value

Comment: what version of kdb are you on?
appears to be some strange behaviour on older version that mean when you pass distinct an atom it actually performs rand "?"

Answer (score 5):

This behavior of distinct was changed in kdb+ 2.7 to block scalar operations;

From README.txt;

```
2011.10.12 - updated, see above entry
FIX

block scalar case for distinct (as it reverted to rand which was confusing)
 e.g. q)distinct 4
q.k - redefine rand:{*1?x} , system:."\\" and faster j10,j12
```

Answer (score 2):

"count distinct" will give you count of the distinct values whereas "distinct count" will give you count of total values as the values are already counted before applying distinct to it.

Lets consider an example.
Eg:

```
t1: ([] a: 1 2 3 1 2 3 4)

select count distinct a from t1 / Output is 4 i.e count of distinct values
select distinct count a from t1 / Output is 7 i.e total count of values
```